# Find extremal points in the closed unit ball of $L^\infty$[0,1]

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

A vector x is extremal in E if for any $0<t<1$,$z,y \in E$, $x=ty + (1-t)z$ implies $x=y=z$. I seek all extremal points on the closed unit ball of $L^\infty[0,1]$.

We know that no vector not on the unit sphere may be extremal, since you can take $\alpha$ to be in $(0, 1-\|f\|_\infty)$ and average the functions $f + \alpha$, $f- \alpha$.

I'm fairly certain, just based on intuition, that any function with $\|f\|=1$ should be extremal but I cannot show this.

EDIT: I've been trying to prove something that's false! I have a new guess:
$\mathcal{E}$= functions of the form: $\mathbf{1}_{A}-\mathbf{1}_{A^c}$ for measurable A $\subset [0,1]$, $\mu(A)>0$ ($\mu$ is Lebesgue Measure)

We claim $\mathcal{E}$ are functions of the form $\mathbf{1}_E-\mathbf{1}_{E^c}, E$ measurable, $\mu(E)>0$. 
Suppose $\sup_{x \in E}|f(x)|<1$ on some set $E$ of positive measure. Then let $0<\alpha<1-\sup_{x \in E}|f(x)|$. We define $$g=\mathbf{1}_E(f-\alpha)+\mathbf{1}_{E^c}f$$ $$h=\mathbf{1}_E(f+\alpha)+\mathbf{1}_{E^c}f$$ and notice both $g,h \in B$ and that $f$ is the average of $g$ and $h$ almost everywhere.

Comment: What is your definition of "extremal point"?

Comment: If $x$ is extremal in $E$ then if $0<t<1$, $y,z \in E$, $x=ty+(1-t)z$ implies that $y=x=z$

Comment: Essentially any convex sum is trivial.

Comment: So is $\chi_{[0,1/2]}$ extremal?

Comment: @kimchi lover ; good comment, my post is updated with a better guess for $\mathcal{E}$

Comment: Much better.  (I touched up your mathjax, btw.) You are tacitly assuming your $L^\infty$ space has real-valued functions only; the complex case is a little more complicated.  Also, your restriction that $\mu(E)>0$ rules out the case of the constant $-1$ function, which has got to be extreme, too.

Comment: $E$ is just a subset of $[0,1]$. The restriction was just to rule out say: $\mathbf{1}_{\mathcal{Q}}$ which would have norm 0 since it is 0 almost everwhere?